# What's wrong with this INSERT stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

Kindly see the SQL Server stored procedure which is simple `INSERT` statement on a single table 'tblSOF'

```
CREATE PROCEDURE InsertINTO_tblSOF_sp
   @SOFID int, @ContractNo nvarchar(15), @SOFNo nvarchar(10), 
   @WONo int, @WORefType nvarchar(50), @WORef nvarchar(50), @InvoiceID int,
   @OrgCode nvarchar(50), @Sec nvarchar(50), @SOFDate datetime,
   @CommenceDate datetime, @LDPerDay money, @DurationDays int,
   @CompletionDate datetime, @TxtIncrmnt int, @TypeofWO nvarchar(50),
   @ActCompletionDate datetime, @DescriptionOfWork nvarchar(100), @Location nvarchar(50), 
   @Status nvarchar(50), @StatusDate datetime, @AccStringID int, @SOFValue money, 
   @LDApplied int, @PartialPayment bit, @Retention bit, @Percent money, 
   @LogRegID int, @RecordedBy nvarchar(50)
AS
BEGIN
   SET NOCOUNT ON;

   INSERT INTO [tblSOF]
 ([SOFID]
 ,[ContractNo]
 ,[SOFNo]
 ,[WONo]
 ,[WORefType]
 ,[WORef]
 ,[InvoiceID]
 ,[OrgCode]
 ,[Sec]
 ,[SOFDate]
 ,[CommenceDate]
 ,[LDPerDay]
 ,[DurationDays]
 ,[CompletionDate]
 ,[TxtIncrmnt]
 ,[TypeofWO]
 ,[ActCompletionDate]
 ,[DescriptionOfWork]
 ,[Location]
 ,[Status]
 ,[StatusDate]
 ,[AccStringID]
 ,[SOFValue]
 ,[LDApplied]
 ,[PartialPayment]
 ,[Retention]
 ,[Percent]
 ,[LogRegID]
 ,[RecordedBy])

 VALUES
 (@SOFID
 ,@ContractNo
 ,@SOFNo
 ,@WONo
 ,@WORefType
 ,@WORef
 ,@InvoiceID
 ,@OrgCode
 ,@Sec
 ,@SOFDate
 ,@CommenceDate
 ,@LDPerDay
 ,@DurationDays
 ,@CompletionDate
 ,@TxtIncrmnt
 ,@TypeofWO
 ,@ActCompletionDate
 ,@DescriptionOfWork
 ,@Location
 ,@Status
 ,@StatusDate
 ,@AccStringID
 ,@SOFValue
 ,@LDApplied
 ,@PartialPayment
 ,@Retention
 ,@Percent
 ,@LogRegID
 ,@RecordedBy)

GO
```

I am stumped with the following error.

Error:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure InsertINTO_tblSOF_sp, Line 80
>   Incorrect syntax near ')'.

Comment: Missing an `END` to pair with the `BEGIN`

Comment: @MartinSmith looks right to me - submit it as an answer

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a trivial syntax error unlikely to benefit future visitors.

Comment: @Liath - I answer these trivial syntax error questions in the comments and vote to close instead.

Comment: @MartinSmith Though I understand your arguing about this I would still favor writing answers as answers instead of comments; to avoid spam one could then still vote to close it ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's missing `END` at the end (you have only `BEGIN`):

```
...
,@RecordedBy)
END

GO
```

Comment: Thanks a lot guys, It was the BEGIN.....END block which were missing. Problem solved